# checkbox and data-toggle conflicts that doesn't allow checkbox check

Tags: html

i can't check the checkbox because i added data-toggle="tab". bt i dont want to remove that data-toggle="tab". is there any idea to make it work .

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown trigger</a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" data-toggle="tab" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
<div class="tab">
<input type="checkbox">
 
</div>  

  <a href="#">Item</a>
 
  </div>
</div>
```

thank you in adavance